# How does this product of matrices define a local diffeomorphism?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $$H_1 := \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\right\},$$ $$H_2 := \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ y & 1\end{pmatrix} \mid y \in \mathbb{R}\right\},$$ and $$H_3 := \left\{\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^\ast\right\}.$$ How does the product map $H_2 \times H_3 \times H_1 \rightarrow \operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ define a local diffeomorphism?

Comment: I think the way you've written the product map is a little bit confusing.  I'd prefer to think of it as a map $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^* \times \mathbb{R} \to$ SL$(2,\mathbb{R})$ which takes $(y,\lambda,x) \mapsto H_2H_3H_1 \in$SL$(2,\mathbb{R})$.  Does this different viewpoint help at all?

Comment: Hint: A map is a local diffeomorphism if its differential is an isomorphism (inverse function theorem).